# Story where grandma rips her grandson's novel/textbook to shreds

Tags: identification-request

I read this story at least 15 years ago in a fairy tale compilation. The story had a teenager reading a novel hidden inside a textbook (forgot if it was math textbook or something else).

I think the story was either set in the real world or in the medieval ages. There was no magical element. I believe I might have read the story in Chinese, since I read it when I was in China.

The grandma was cleaning (I think) and she asked him if he was studying. He said yes. And then the grandma came over and ripped the books right out of his hands and said something like "what's this? this doesn't look like a textbook" and then shredded the novel to pieces. I think she might have also beaten him severely with a broomstick.

Comment: Welcome to Literature! Was this story set in the real world or in some kind of fantasy world? How long ago is "many years ago"? Was it written in English? Where did you read it? Every little detail might help someone to identify it, and I'm sure you remember more about it than you realise :-)